# Android How to get time format day month year of all images in gallery of device

Tags: android, time, image-gallery

I have used this code to get time of all images in device. But it return value Long. I want get format day, month, year. How to i can get format day, month, year ?
My code:

```
val imageProjection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        )

        val imageSortOrder = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED} DESC"

        val cursor = requireActivity().contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            imageProjection,
            null,
            null,
            imageSortOrder
        )
   val date_time=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN)
   var dateTaken=cursor.getLong(date_time)
//But dateTaken return value Long not format day, month, year
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method to get date by giving it `Long` or `milliseconds` and `Date Format`

it will parse `milliseconds` to the given format

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
{
    // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

    // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date. 
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
     return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Call it like this

```
getDate(82233213123L, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS")
```